# i need to get the value of x when x greater than y

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
df = pd.DataFrame(json_response["data"]["candles"], columns=['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume'])
```

```
x=400
y=300
if(x > y):
print(x)
```

Here `x` is one column in csv with values and `y` another column if the first column `x > y` then print value of `x` where the column value associated

Comment: i have updated the question please help @jezrael

Comment: In data sample missing it is DataFrame, there are compre scalars, what cannot be used for compare by Series or columns in pandas DataFrame

Comment: okay i will update with data frame

Comment: ok, so I cannot run your code with no error :(

Comment: ... because json_response is not defined

Comment: my json_response is defined like `ohlc=['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close']`

Comment: i am getting output like true or false but i need value of that true

Comment: example x > y its printing true but i need the value of x where x is greater

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just select the rows meeting your criteria, then print the column you're interested in:

```
# result is series
print(df(df["x"]>df["y"])["x"])

# result is array of integers
for result in df(df["x"]>df["y"])["x"].values:
    print(result)
```

Comment: its not working i just need like `if (x > y): print (value of x where x is greater)`

Comment: Extended my example, that prints the values only, not the series object.